# How do I remove cloud-init backing image from my VM?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, qemu, cloud-init

I am moving a VM from Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS KVM host to a RHEL 8.9 Ootpa KVM host.

When I try to start the VM on the destination (RHEL) host I see,

---

error: Cannot access backing file '/var/iso/jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img' of storage file '/home/libvirt/images/nsn.qcow2' (as uid:107, gid:107): No such file or directory

---

**virsh domblklist nsn** 
says,

```
 Target   Source
----------------------------------
 sda      /var/kvm/nsn-seed.iso
 vda      /mpass/vm-images/nsn.qcow2
```

I created this VM years ago so I don't remember how I used cloud-init with virt-install.
I'd rather not copy the jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img or nsn-seed.iso to the new host since A.) the Red Hat destination host would probably not know what to do with them and B.) they would be clutter even if they did work.

I chopped out the xml syntax that contained the lines regarding the ISO image and tried starting the VM but it failed again with the same error.

the /etc/fstab of my guest (nsn) looks odd to me.

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   discard,errors=remount-ro       0 1
LABEL=UEFI      /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0 1
```

No UUIDs for the disks. Weird.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I'm just on the way out, and I haven't used a backing file, but my first thought is that the backing file *is* pretty much the entire Ubuntu image, and you can't just throw it away. This is part of `qemu-img` and should work identically on RHEL. I personally would integrate it into a new stand-alone `qcow2` image on your Ubuntu host before running it on RHEL - look up `qemu-image backing-chain`. This obviously will be much bigger than your original `qcow2` image.

Comment: Thanks for commenting and I agree. The file utility says /var/iso/jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img is a qcow2 image so perhaps I need to consolidate the two disk files associated with the VM.

Comment: I mounted jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img and found nothing specific to the VM. I mean no configuration at all. When I mounted nsn.qcow2, all the config data is there. So the jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img seems not to be the 'real' disk.

Comment: Without understanding what I was doing I ran, 'qemu-img rebase -f qcow2 -b /home/libvirt/images/nsn.qcow2  -F qcow2 /var/iso/jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img' (while the VM was shut down) and wound up with jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img as the only disk. Somehow jammy-server-cloudimg-amd64.img absorbed my VM's configuration and the VM ran when I started it. Then I shut it down and renamed the .img to nsn.qcow2 and updated the xml with the original disk path. It's running fine despite my ham-fisted kludge work.